# How to pass the name checked from checkbox to another activity

Tags: android, database, checkbox

I am currently having a difficulty in passing the name from the checkbox from one activity to another activity. Actually the name should be inserted into my database table after it is checked and then it will be passed to the activity mentioned earlier. Anyone have any idea on doing it? Any help provided will be greatly appreciated.

For reference, the codes for my project.

```
  BuddyDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        //ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id)
            {

               Cursor cursor = null;

               cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
               Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsList.this, Create_Events.class);
               intent.putExtra("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(buddyDB.KEY_NAME)));
               startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

        Uri allContacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");

        Cursor c = managedQuery(allContacts, null, null, null, null);

        String[] columns = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[] views = new int[]  {R.id.contactCheckbox};

        startManagingCursor(c);

        SimpleCursorAdapter friendsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contacts_list, c, columns, views);
        this.setListAdapter(friendsAdapter);



    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        buddyDB.open();
        //long name_id;
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
        c.moveToPosition(position);

        /*TextView contactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValue = contactName.getText().toString();

        name_id = buddyDB.insertNames(NameValue);


        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Selected: " + buddiesList[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        buddyDB.close();*/


            nameCheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.contactCheckbox);
            nameCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
                {               
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked)
                    {
                        long name_id;
                        String NameValue = nameCheck.getText().toString();
                        name_id = buddyDB.insertNames(NameValue);
                        /*if(isChecked)
                        {
                            nameCheck = 1;
                        }else
                        {
                            nameCheck = 0;
                        }*/                 
                    }                   
                });     
            buddyDB.close();        
    }

}
```

Again, any help from anyone will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: whats not working?? Your code seems fine. Are you getting any exception or data not getting inserted...??

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the data is not being inserted when the name is being checked.

Comment: Homework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362608/cant-insert-checkbox-values-into-sqlitedatabase-from-listview ?

Comment: But it's not answered yet so I can ask this question still.

Answer (score 0):

use this code where you want to pass parameter to another activity.

```
Intent n = new Intent(actA.this , actB.class);
n.putExtra("name", NameValue);
startActivity(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

To pass the name values from oneActivity

```
Intent n = new Intent(actA.this , actB.class);
n.putExtra("name", NameValue);
startActivity(n);
```

To get the given values

```
Intent igetlist = getIntent();
String singleid = igetlist.getExtras().getString("name");
```